# Is my Hostgator dedicated IP used any more if I use CloudFlare DNS?

Tags: web-services, dns, seo, ip-address, cloudflare

I'm hosting my website with Hostgator and I have a paid dedicated IP address for my host.
Today I have made an account on CloudFlare and replaced my old hostgator DNS with ClodFlare's DNS.

My question is: If I've changed my Hostgator DNS with CloudFlare DNS that dedicated IP from Hostgator will be used like before or I'm paying for it for nothing and my website uses CloudFlare IP from now on?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about terms and conditions and/or operational behavior of hostingproviders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using CloudFlare your domain would resolve to 2 CloudFlare IPs.

CloudFlare is a reverse proxy, so once you point to our DNS - the domain will resolve to our IP addresses, and then within our system we'd still connect to your web server at HostGator.

So the dedicated IP would effectively be a bit useless once you begin using CloudFlare - since anyone coming to the site will see the domain resolving to CloudFlare IPs anyway.

p.s. I work at CloudFlare.